# What Does a Subscript Do to a Number?

Tags: notation, fibonacci-numbers

So I had a math question that had a formula for that said T<sub>n</sub>= ar<sup>n-1</sup> Where a is the first sequence and r is the common ratio. For example, in the sequence 10,40,160,640,..., a=10, and r=40/10=160/40=640/160=4. n is the n<sup>th</sup> term.

Then it asked me to find the product of the 10th and 13th term and the quotient of the 10th and 13th term in exponetial notation from the given sequence.
1/2,1,2,4,8,16, ...

So I found a=1/2 and r=2
Then I solved it. ar<sup>13-1</sup>=T<sub>13</sub> Or 1. This confused me and I re-did it several time for both n=10 and n=13 but both being 1. I tried doing the first example sequence(and yes, I am ignoring T<sub>n</sub>. Specifically the n because I don't know what it does.) and it was always missing a 0 of had an extra 0. However, unlike the second sequence, it did not always equal 1 as you change the value of n.

Comment: What do you mean "but both being 1"?

Comment: $ar^{13-1} = ar^{12} = a \times \underbrace{r \times r \times \cdot \times r}_{\textrm{12 times}}$. If you multiply $1/2$ by twelve $2$s, you definitely don't get $1$.

Comment: Oh. I made a mistake. I thought (ar) but you are right. It is just r to the power. I was thinking (a x r) to the power of 13-1. Thanks. I still don't know what the superscript does though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone has a sequence $T$, they often refer to the $n$th element as $T_n$. So if your sequence is $1/2, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, \ldots$, then $T_1 = 1/2$, $T_2 = 1$, etc.

For a geometric series, you have $T_n = ar^{n-1}$, like you said. The $10$th term is $T_{10} = ar^9$ and the $13$th term is $T_{13} = ar^{12}$. Instead of computing these and then multiplying them together, let's multiply them together first, then plug in $a$ and $r$:
$$ T_{10} T_{13} = ar^9 \cdot ar^{12} = a^2 r^{21} = (1/2^2) \cdot 2^{21} = 2^{19} = 524288 $$

The quotient is actually even easier:
$$ \frac{T_{10}}{T_{13}} = \frac{ar^9}{a^{12}} = \frac{1}{r^3} = \frac{1}{8} $$

Answer (score 2):

$T_n$ is the name of the given sequence. The subscript simply refers to the index, or what term you are at. That is, you can write out $T_n$ as an ordered list: $T_0, T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4, ... , T_n$.

So $T_{13}$ is stating, this is the thirteenth term of the sequence $T$. So to find the product of the thirteenth and tenth term,  it is asking $T_{10} \cdot T_{13}$.

I am assuming they want you to find it for a general geometric sequence. This means $T_{10} \cdot T_{13} = (ar^{10-1})(ar^{13-1})$, which can be simplified via properties of exponents.